# Did I make a dangling reference?

Tags: c++, c++11

Normally, I'd omit the `std::vector` but that would require me to make my function take a `const int&`. What I want to know is since there's a temporary vector if I have a dangling reference. Is it safe to modify its elements?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void foo(int& i)
{
    i = 42;
}

void foo(int&& i)
{
    std::cout << "int&&";
}

int main()
{
    for (auto&& i : std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3})
    {
        foo(std::forward<decltype(i)>(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Your code does not hav a dangling reference. 2) If you _do_ have a dangling reference then it's not ok to modify the value it references.

Comment: _"Normally, I'd omit the std::vector but that would require me to make my function take a const int&."_ Eh?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If he drops the `std::vector<int>` part then the deduced `initializer_list<int>` will only allow `const` access to its elements.

Comment: @Praetorian: Oh right, he was speaking lexically then.

Answer (score 2):

Your temporary `vector` survives for the lifetime of the loop, due to the way in which the ranged-for statement is defined. Therefore, there are no dangling references here and your program is safe. Modify away.